# libde265 decode hevc and save to .jpg file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, jpeg, hevc

I need to decode some hevc file to jpg, I can do this with ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i test.hevc test.jpg`

I want to integrate ffmpeg with my program, but the ffmpeg library seems to be large and not that easy to build on Win32. So I found another small and independent library libde265. Its sample demonstrates how to get every pixel of the hevc image, but it seems not able to save to a .jpg file.

What's the simplest way to save a `de265_image` to a jpg file?

Comment: why not just run the command inside your program ?

Comment: This causes disk io, I'm writing a server to handle lots of these requests. The performance would be better if it works without harddisk io, all in memory.